# Find and replace within attribute values

Tags: jquery, html, image, attributes, attr

I have this HTML code:

```html
<div class='images'>
  <img class='thumbnail' src='background/01.png' />  
  <img class='thumbnail' src='background/02.png' />  
  <img class='thumbnail' src='background/03.png' />  
  <img class='thumbnail' src='background/04.png' />  
  <img class='thumbnail' src='background/05.png' />  
</div>
```

I am looking to change every "background" to "category". I am using this jQuery snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $('.thumbnail').attr('src', $('.thumbnail').attr('src').replace('background', 'category'));
});
```

But the result :

```html
<div class='images'>
  <img class='thumbnail' src='category/01.png' />  
  <img class='thumbnail' src='category/01.png' />  
  <img class='thumbnail' src='category/01.png' />  
  <img class='thumbnail' src='category/01.png' />  
  <img class='thumbnail' src='category/01.png' />  
</div>
```

Please note : I can't change img class. Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that it's better practice to use `prop()` for this. Secondly, you can pass `prop()` a function to handle each specific element in the matched set and update its value. Try this:

```
$('.thumbnail').prop('src', function(i, val) {
    return val.replace('background', 'category');
});
```